# "entry.isEditable()" not working on Craft CMS 4

Tags: craft4

Do the "isEditable" property of Entry still exists?
Whats the best way to achieve the same functionallity in Craft 4?

```
{% if entry.isEditable() %}
```

After I upgraded from Craft 3 to 4, all my "edit links" are gone from the website.
Looking at the Craft's documentation, it's missing this property in v4 docs (but exist in v3).

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-elements-entry.html#public-properties
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html#public-properties

Answer (score 2):

The `getIsEditable()` method was removed in Craft 4.0, in favour of some new element methods like [`canView()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-base-elementinterface.html#method-canview) and [`canSave()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-base-elementinterface.html#method-cansave). These were brought in with the new "unified element editor" and AFAIK these methods are only [mentioned in the plugin upgrade guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/updating-plugins.html#unified-element-editor), not the main Craft 4 upgrade guide. They are still totally fine to use in front end templates, though.

To replace `getIsEditable()`, the closest equivalent is probably the `canSave()` method:

```
{% if currentUser and entry.canSave(currentUser) %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Also, in Craft 4.3 the new global Twig functions [`canView()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#canview) and [`canSave()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#cansave) were added, which wraps the methods mentioned above. I personally prefer to use the global functions, as they typically make a conditional like the above a lot terser:

```
{% if canSave(entry) %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```